# Now to disable pre-rendering on build in Next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When ever I run the build command in my next js project, I get errors that says `occurred prerendering page "/". ENOENT: no such file or directory, open $HOME/project_name/.next/server/chunks/file_name`. This error occurs for all pages in my app, and not just root `/`.

I am very new to next js and I dont understand the SSR and other nextjs stuff at all. This error appears in dev as well, but the app does run as it should. So, I just want the build command to ignore this error message so that I can at least have a built app that I can deploy for demo porpose.

How can I do so?